# What are limitations of presentViewController over UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am confused about "In which situations we have to use `presentViewController` and  `UINavigationController`".
I had read so many documents, but I haven't  found accurate explanation. We can always use `UInavigationController` then what is the use of `presentViewController` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push a navigation controller into other navigation controller.
You can present a navigation controller above other navigation controller.

If you push a view controller into the navigation controller, view controller's view cover only area inside navigation controller.
If you present a view controller, view  controller's view cover the window hierarchy (user can't interact with other parts of the application).

You can don't use UINavigationController to present some UIViewController. You should care about "close" button to let user to close presented UIViewController

I've create test project to illustrate my answer https://github.com/K-Be/PresentTest

Comment: dear Andrew i have gone through your code . i am not talking about presenting the navigation controller with presentVC mothod. i want the difference. my exact question is "suppose i am able to do navigation like 1->2->3 and poping likie 3->2->1 using UINavigationController .The same thing is achieved using presentviewcontroller and dismisviewcontroller method. what is different".And from your answer i understood that all controllers views play in uinavigationcontrollers main view only .But if we use presentViewcontroller window's only rootviewcontroller becomes our presented vC right?

Comment: No, root viewController does not become presenting view controller. If you'll use present  method, you'll get different window hierarchy. You can see it in example.
You can achieved, same visual results (by using push and present methods), but them will be different in viewControllers hierarchy, and window hierarchy. 
All different is inside.

Comment: can you give any links to understand viewControllers hierarchy, and window hierarchy. or else can you explain please?

Comment: you mean it is some thing like Container View Controller concept.suppose if we present a VC2 from VC1 than VC1 becomes parent and VC2 is child? and if we dissmiss VC2 then that does not become child.

Comment: [it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW47) about views.

[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW23) about view controllers.

Comment: Yes, presenting view controller modally like container view controller concept, but parent view controller of presented view controller == nil.  [about presenting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1)

Comment: at that time uinavigationcontroller was also implemented uising container view controller concept internally. then in which situations we have to use thease two. in this context i think there is no difference. because both are implemented using container view controller concept.

Answer (score 2):

`UINavigationController` maintains the stack of the controllers that are being viewed. So once you push through 1->2->3 view controllers then you can pop in 3->2->1 manner. Unless you don't change the stack this kind of flow is maintained by `UINavigationController`. Now lets say you want to show 4th view controller without disturbing the above flow. Then you can use `presentViewController`.

This is the simplest and basic is for using navigation controller and `presentViewController`

Comment: what is meaning of "Now lets say you want to show 4th view controller without disturbing the above flow" this line you mean if i want to go to from 3->4 viewcontroller i have to use presentViewController? here also i can use UIInavigationController. what is need of presentViewController.And for maintaining this 3->2->1 flow i can i also use dismisviewcontroller  method from 3 to 2 to 1.here what is the need of uinavigationcontroller.